# Ruby on Rails simple output style fix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Input file is an excel file and the excel file has headers like author, 2ndauthor, 3rdauthor.

So the input xlsx looks like

```
Title    Author     2ndAuthor     3rdAuthor    4thAuthor
E=MC^2   Einstein
DNA      Watson     Crick
AAA      BB         BBB           CCC
```

But currently the ruby on rails program does something like

```
if not contents["#{record.title} (#{record.author} paper)"]
  contents += "*[[#{record.title} (#{record.author} paper)]]\r\n"
end
```

So the output of the ruby program looks like

```
E=MC^2 (Einstein paper)
DNA (Watson paper)
AAA (BB paper)
```

But I want to include 2ndauthor, 3rdauthor,... to get

```
E=MC^2 (Einstein paper)
DNA (Watson and Crick paper)
AAA (BB, BBB, and CCC paper)
```

So, comma is added between authors only when there are 3 or more than 3 authors.

Is there any brilliant way to do this?

**added question**

If

```
"#{title} (#{author} paper)"
```

was generating

```
AAA (BB paper)
```

then will

```
"#{title}" + " ([#{author},#{2ndauthor},#{3rdauthor},#{4thauthor}].delete_if{|val| val.nil?}.to_sentence" + " paper)"
```

generate

```
AAA (BB, BBB, and CCC paper)
```

?

Comment: If you like the answer, please accept it by clicking the check under answer number.

Answer (score 1):

This code should be close, but I haven't actually run it. It takes advantage of two nice features, the Rails Array::to_sentence and Ruby Array::delete_if

```
# code assumes record member names are the same as input xlsx
# change if otherwise. 
# code also assume blank columns will be nil in record. If not, change delete_if block
# accordingly
# also assume there is some array of records

contents = ""
records.each do |record|
    contents += "\r\n" if contents != ""
    contents += "#{record.Title} (#{[record.Title, record.Author, record.2ndAuthor, record.3rdAuthor, record.4thAuthor].delete_if{|val| val.nil?}.to_sentence}) paper"
end
```

Comment: @Steve_Wilhem Thank you but as I wrote " and " should come just before the last non-empty author, and "," should come just after non-last authors if the total number of authors are 3 or more. I guess your code currently does not take that into consideration?

Comment: It should, that is what to_sentence does.

Comment: @Steve_Wilhem It should look like DNA (Watson and Crick paper), so it should be like Title (Author and 2ndAuthor paper) Does to_sentence also add parenthesis after "paper" and before the first author?

Comment: @Steve_Wilhem What I am asking is essentially about the added question that I wrote. (I appended it to my question.)

Comment: My answer was edited to add parentheses around the author/paper section.